# How bypass filters in sql injections

Tags: php, sql-injection

I'm doing SQL injection exercises, and I cannot bypass a filter that replace with nothing ("") the occurences of **=** and **OR**.

The web page have a login interface, and the query performed is:

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'
```

My idea was passing ***pippo*** as user and ***' OR 'a'='a'; --*** as password but of course with that filter, my string is harmless.

I tried also with ***' || 'a'like'a'; --*** but, nothing happens. some advices?

Comment: Are you saying that the filter replaces instances of `=` and `OR` with nothing, or that instances of nothing are replaced with `=` and `OR`? Your wording is ambiguous.

Comment: = and or with "" of course

Comment: READ HERE: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: How about simply ending the query after the username? Set `$username` to your username and concatenate with `'; #` and be done with it?

Comment: @MateiMihai `OR` and `=` are replaced, like he said. So your input would become `1'  usernameusername; --`

Comment: sure that works, I'm asking why `'; --` instead didn't worked...

Comment: username + `'; --` should have worked aswell. Maybe that gets replaced too?

Comment: This is basically the same question as [SQL injection with php filtering](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23626697/53114).

Answer (score -1):

Using `pippo'; #` for $username and **anything** for $password results in this query:

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username='pippo'; # ' and password='... anything ...'
```

Which bypasses the password check entirely.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the downvote?

Comment: it works, I could pass login, but the username is `pippo';#`!!!!